# I have a problem with syntax in nodes (data Structure)

Tags: python, data-structures

This code should create a node but I have a problem with it I tried to fix it but I couldn`t

I want to know why there is a problem at in the Linked_List (Next_Node)

that  is what show in the error "(Cannot assign member "next_node" for type "node"
Expression of type "node | None" cannot be assigned to member "next_node" of class "node"
Type "node | None" cannot be assigned to type "None"
Type cannot be assigned to type "None")"

```
class node :
    data = None
    next_node = None

def __init__(self , data) :
    self.data = data

def __repr__(self) :
    return "<node data: %s>" % self.data
```

class linked_list :

```
def __init__(self ):
    self.head = None

def add (self , data):
    new_node = node(data)
    new_node.next_node = self.head
    self.head = new_node 
def __repr__ (self):
    nodes =[]
    current = self.head
    while current :
        if current is self.head:
            nodes.append ("[:head %s ]" % current.data)
        elif current.next.node is None :
            nodes.append ("[tail: %s ]" % current.data)
        else :
            nodes.append ("[:%s ]" % current.data)
    current = current.next_node
    return  "->".join(nodes)
```

Comment: sorry I didn't know... I edit it now (thanks to tell me)

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. Unfortunately, it still isn't very clear. _Specifically_, what do you mean by "but I have a problem with it"? Are you getting an error message? No error message, but it doesn't behave the way you want? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead? (Also, ideally you'd boil this down to a [mre], emphasis on "minimal". I'm sure the problem can be shown with much less code than what is here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with current attempt:

1. The Node class as pointed by John Gordon is wrongly constructed. The `data` and `next_node` should be in `__init__` method.
2. The  `add` method is not adding new node in correct position.
3. The `__repr__` is not looping through all the nodes in the linked list because of wrong indentation.

**Updated code:**

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<node data: %s>" % self.data


class linked_list:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0

        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next_node
        return count

    def add(self, data):
        new_node = node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next_node != None:
                current = current.next_node
            current.next_node = new_node

    def __repr__(self):
        nodes = []
        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current is self.head:
                nodes.append("[:head %s ]" % current.data)
            elif current.next_node is None:
                nodes.append("[tail: %s ]" % current.data)
            else:
                nodes.append("[:%s ]" % current.data)
            current = current.next_node
        return "->".join(nodes)


l = linked_list()
l.add(1)
l.add(2)
l.add(3)
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[:head 1 ]->[:2 ]->[tail: 3 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class node :
    data = None
    next_node = None

    def __init__(self , data):
        self.data = data
```

I think the problem is because of the `node` class definition.

The way you've defined the `next_node` variable, it is a direct attribute of the class, so it is shared among *all* instances of the class.

I think you intended that attribute to be inside the `__init__` method, so that each instance would have its own separate copy of that variable:

```
class node :
    def __init__(self , data) :
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None
```

Comment: i did it but the problem still there it fix one error but it still has other